# Multiple authentication schemes for HTTP 'Authorization' Header

Tags: http, rest, security

For our api user we need two styles of authentication:

- authenticate the api-user (mobile-device, partner integration)
- authenticate a specific "normal" user, which owns data on our side

The standard challenge vs. response is handled through `WWW-Authenticate` and `Authorization` Headers. I want to reuse this.

I have following use-case: On first level we authenticate the api-user (e.g. mobile device), for some api-actions we also need to authenticate a user (e.g. user of mobile device). So we have a special case where we need two authentications schemes "at once".

Looking at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html I cannot see that having two different schemes inside one 'Authorization' Header is possible.

```
// I just made up delimiter ';'
Authorization: Digest .... ; CustomXXX ...
```

Am I correct, if so is there an alternative?

Comment: We introduced a custom X-MYCOMPANY-Authorization header

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple HTTP Authorization headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282578/multiple-http-authorization-headers)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, Authorization can only take one set of credentials.

Comment: Yeah, for that reason I cannot reuse the WWW-Authenticate for my problem but go for a custom X-xxx Authentication scoped Header.