# Mixing Windows Authentication and Token Authentication

Tags: angularjs, token, windows-authentication

I am implementing a token authentication into a system that has legacy Windows Authentication. I have followed some token examples and have come up with the following. Here is my request header that I am issuing in Angular UI:

```
authorization:bearer - token value
Authorization:Negotiate some value
```

I am adding token to the request like this:

```
config.headers.authorization = "bearer " + access_token;
```

As you can see I end up with two a/A authorizations. The response from the server is:

```
HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name
```

I am assuming it's because of these two entries. I have tried using capital A for my token entry but the response was the same.

Any idea, please?

Edit 1

```
    GET /api/case HTTP/1.1
    Authorization   bearer value
    Accept  application/json, text/plain, */*
    Referer http://localhost/main.aspx
    Accept-Language en-US
    Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
   User-Agent   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0)  like Gecko
   Cookie   ASP.NET_SessionId=value
   Host localhost
   Authorization    Negotiate value
```

Comment: Any chance you could include all of the headers for the request that fails? (from the browser network monitor or something like Fiddler)

Comment: It seems that having multiple authentication headers is the problem (e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282578/multiple-http-authorization-headers). Have you tried using just the token?

Comment: I will look into a link you are providing, but meanwhile .. I am not adding Authorization    Negotiate .... it gets there somehow.

Comment: In that case, it seems likely that IIS is set up to require authentication, and the "Authorization: Negotiate..." header you are seeing is part of the negotiation process that it is kicking off. For authentication issues, I've found Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to be much more helpful than the browser network tools as it lets you see all of the requests.

Comment: I am not using Browser tools. I am using Charles. But I think you have explained it. Thanks