# verifyIdToken in Google Auth signin

Tags: reactjs, node.js, google-oauth

I need `idToken` for `client.verifyIdToken` for this google function but I don't know how to get idToken using any Google APIs? Please anyone knows the method. thank you.

Comment: Would this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42405439/how-to-verify-google-auth-token-at-server-side-in-node-js

Comment: No @Fide this method needs to call after I get `idToken`, this is what I can't find, here in your given link there's `token` param which is idToken and need that