# Using nested authentication with Google IAP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, authorization, google-cloud-run, google-iap

I deployed a 3rd party webapp which uses basic authentication for access on [Google Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/). I additionally wanted to protect the endpoint by allowing only Google-authenticated users of the organization access. Both these methods use the `Authorization` header of the request and I cannot get it to work.

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282578/multiple-http-authorization-headers) post, providing both credentials in one field. My reasoning was, that GCP should select the strongest credential mechanism it supports - bearer - and leave the basic credentials for the webap. I have no idea if the webapp could have dealt with it because Google's reverse proxy already barred my access.

```
curl "-HAuthorization: bearer ${bearer_token}, basic ${base64_userpw}" https://my-google-endpoint.com
```

-> 401 Unauthorized

I also tried `Proxy-Authorization` with no different result.
    curl "-HProxy-Authorization: bearer ${bearer_token}" "-HAuthorization: basic ${base64_userpw}" https://my-google-endpoint.com

Is there a way to get nested authentication to work with Google's reverse proxy? I was able to get past the reversed proxy by only supplying the bearer but naturally hit the wall at the service. With deactivated authentication on proxy side I was able to authenticate with the service using the basic credentials.

P.S.:
I am not using a browser to access the webapp but command line tools.

Comment: Where does IAP sit in here? Infront of Cloud Run?

Comment: I might be mistaken in the terminology. I configured Cloud Run to allow only authenticated access and assumed that it is the same principle as IAP.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot mix Authorization mechanisms with IAP. Everything after the `bearer` keyword is considered the token string.

One solution is to change your Basic Authorization HTTP header from using `Authorization` to a custom HTTP header. Something like `X-MyApp-Authorization`. Then your app processes the custom header to handle the Basic Authorization mechanism.

**[Update 2021-08-17]**

My original answer is partially wrong. Google's solution is currently broken.

Cloud Run is behind Google Cloud IAP. The client making a request can use two HTTP Authorization headers:

- Authorization: <**application authorization token**>
- Proxy-Authorization: Bearer <**IDENTITY_TOKEN**>

If a valid ID token is found in a **Proxy-Authorization** header, IAP authorizes the request with it. After authorizing the request, IAP passes the **Authorization** header to your application without processing the content.

[Authenticating from Proxy-Authorization Header](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_proxy-authorization_header)

This means the OP was on the right track using the Proxy-Authorization header. However, this feature does not work.

Create an Identity Token:

Use **curl** to verify that the token works with a Cloud Run endpoint that requires the Invoker role:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" $endpoint
```

That works. Now try the Proxy-Authorization header:

```
curl -H "Proxy-Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" $endpoint
```

That fails with a 403.

Now try both headers:

```
curl -H "Proxy-Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Authorization: Bearer $ANOTHER_TOKEN" $endpoint
```

That fails with 401 "The access token could not be verified"

```
gcloud auth print-identity-token
```

I am using documented methods to use two authorization headers, but this feature does not work.

The PHP SDK did not have the proxy-authorization header support added until June 25, 2021. I created a test application from Google's example. That also failed with the same errors.

[June 25, 2021 Patch](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-php/commit/aaf236397850fefd28fac32ccc2c897977d4cf6e)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I took the Dockerfile of the service and just deployed it. I therefore did not delve deep into re-configuring the uwsgi service.

Comment: Thanks, I found out after spending too much time redoing everything that my configuration works fine using a regular Authorization key. I was planning on using Proxy-Authorization from the start as the application will need internal authorization, but using a custom header seems like a good solution.

Comment: Reproduced the same broken feature and logged this in Google's IssueTracker if you would like to follow along: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/214408198

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen to work if you send *two* Authorization headers, like `curl -H "Authorization: bearer foo" -H "Authorization: basic bar"` ?

--Matthew, Google Cloud IAP engineering

Comment: Better to add this as a comment as it is not an answer.

Comment: @Matthew when you pass in a basic authentication token in Authorization header and the IAP JWT token in Proxy-Authorization it works.  If the Authorization header contains another JWT token, IAP fails.