# Postman - Access API that secured by Authentication: Bearer Token behind Google Identity Aware Proxy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, postman, identity-aware-proxy, google-cloud-identity-aware-proxy

**Background:**
I have an API that previously running behind VPN. The API it self implement JWT Authentication for some path, so we have to attach:

```
Authorization: Bearer <jwt_token xxxx>
```

We just update our API to run behind Google Identity Aware Proxy and we follow the official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto). Everything working perfectly except for every path that need the JWT Authentication. The IAP mechanism also use:

```
Authorization: Bearer xxxx
```

And will overide the existing `Authentication:` header. Any suggestions without changing the existing code?

Thank you.

Comment: The Google recommendation is to use the **Proxy-Authorization** header for IAP which leaves the **Authorization** header for your app authorization. https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_proxy-authorization_header However, read the notes in my SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59297859/8016720

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by John, you can use two separate headers for the tokens.
If you encounter [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59297859/8016720) error, you can report it via [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).
There is also a similar case being tracked [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192912637) which you may find helpful.

Comment: Thanks guys for the answer, my bad for not reading the documentation carefully. The Proxy-Authorization solved this. Thanks again. Credits for @john-hanley