# GCP Cloud Run service-to-service Authentication using multiple Token

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, http-headers, google-cloud-run

I want to build a Cloud Run to Cloud Run communication and use this how-to:
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service
I generate a id token and add them to the Authorization: Bearer ID_TOKEN header. My problem is, that I also need to send a custom JWT Token in the Authorization header.
Is there a way to pass both token in the Authorization header without a custom header? Or has google cloud the option for a alternative header?

Comment: You need to check your OWN token in your OWN header key. I don't see any other solution :(

Comment: Review my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59297859/8016720 Google IAP supports HTTP **Proxy-Authorization** header: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_proxy-authorization_header

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks, I tried it with Proxy-Authorization but it doesn't work as excepted. But I can try it again... may be the custom header is currently the only solution...

Comment: The header does not work for me either. That is why I linked to my previous answer. I expect that this will work at some point soon otherwise Google would not be updating the SDKs.