# Multiple authorization using swagger OpenAPI 3.0 with Express and JSON format

Tags: node.js, json, express, swagger, openapi

The project has two authorization systems, basic auth and bearer. I need for each request after clicking on the "try it out" and "execute" buttons to attach to the request the Authorization headers, in which there will be a Basic line and a jwt header, in which there will be a bearer token. The problem is that I can attach these headers individually, but not together. There is a feeling that both authorizations want to write to the Authorization header and one of them overwrites the other, even though I explicitly indicated the header names in the schema.

My schemas:

```
    {
    "securitySchemes": {
        "Bearer": {
            "in": "header",
            "name": "jwt",
            "type": "http",
            "scheme": "bearer"
          
        },
        "basicAuth": {
            "type": "http",
            "scheme": "basic"
        }
      }
   }
```

and how I use it:

```
    {
    "/channel/base-list": {
        "get": {
            "tags": [
                "CMS Channel"
            ],
            "security": [
                {
                    "Bearer": [],
                    "basicAuth": []
                }
            ],
            "summary": "Get _id and title of all channels",
            "produces": [
                "application/json"
            ],
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "in": "query",
                    "name": "count",
                    "required": false,
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "Integer"
                    },
                    "default": 25,
                    "example": 10
                },
                {
                    "in": "query",
                    "name": "search",
                    "required": false,
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "description": "Channel name"
                }
            ],
            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "A list of channels",
                    "content": {
                        "application/json": {
                            "schema": {
                                "$ref": "#/definitions/get-channel-base-list"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use swagger-ui-express for node.JS and OpenAPI 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A request can contain [only one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29288935/113116) `Authorization` header, and the `Authorization` header can only contain a [single set of credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3762135/113116) (i.e. either Basic or Bearer, but not both). Your use case is not supported by the HTTP protocol.